# Keep getting many-to-many relationships and I don't understand why

Tags: relationship, filemaker

I have three tables:

1. Student - a table with student information including program, year entered, etc. Each student has a unique ID.
2. Fellowship packages - each academic year has a selection of fellowships available, though some packages can occur in multiple years. Each package has amounts associated for each semester during the academic year.
3. Awards - I want a table which has entries for: student, academic year of award, package, amounts associated with each package.

I should say, I also will need a field in "Awards" that denotes the funding source for each semester in each award.

The "Awards" table is linked to the "Student" table by the students ID#. It's linked to the "Package" by Academic Year. My problem is that I keep getting many-to-many relationships between "Awards" and "Packages", even if I create a separate table with just a list of the years and go through that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*keep getting many-to-many relationships*". Are you referring to the display on the relationships graph? -- In any case, if "*each academic year has a selection of fellowships available*" then obviously you cannot use the academic year as the match field. Use a unique PackageID, same as you do with students. Otherwise the award (and subsequently the student) will be related to **all** packages available in that year.

Comment: Michael is right and I just would like to add that if you require further assistance, you should provide some screenshots of your relationship graph and fields.

Comment: I actually woke up this morning thinking that I probably needed to assign each package-year combination a unique serial number, which is something I was trying to avoid. Thank you both and, if I need further help, I will definitely include screenshots.

Comment: In a pinch, you could assign unique IDs to packages, and use both this ID and the year as the match fields to `Awards`. However, good practice warrants a unique ID for every record, in every table. This is something to embrace, not to avoid. -- Note that strictly speaking, you should have 4 tables: `Students -< Awards >- PackageYears >- Packages`. But in practice it may be acceptable to use a value list instead of the `Packages` table.